# Задача Military Time из SoloLearn Ruby

Tags: ruby

Условие: You want to convert the time from a 12 hour clock to a 24 hour clock. If you are given the time on a 12 hour clock, you should output the time as it would appear on a 24 hour clock.

Task:
Determine if the time you are given is AM or PM, then convert that value to the way that it would appear on a 24 hour clock.

Input Format:
A string that includes the time, then a space and the indicator for AM or PM.

Output Format:
A string that includes the time in a 24 hour format (XX:XX)

Sample Input:
1:15 PM

Sample Output:
13:15

Вот, то, что я написал, проваливается на 3 и 5 тестах
Заранее прошу прощение за код без пробелов SoloLearn сжал

```
time = gets.chomp.split 
h_a_m = time[0].split(":") 
hours = h_a_m[0].to_i 
 
if time[1] == "AM" 
 
 if hours == 12 
 hours = "0" 
 h_a_m[0] = hours 
 arr = h_a_m.join(":") 
 puts arr 
 else 
 puts time[0] 
 end 
else 
 if hours == 12 
 hours = hours.to_s 
 h_a_m[0] = hours 
 arr = h_a_m.join(":") 
 puts arr 
 else 
 hours += 12 
 hours = hours.to_s 
 h_a_m[0] = hours 
 arr = h_a_m.join(":") 
 puts arr 
 end 
 
end
´´´
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
require 'time'
input = '1:05 PM'
result = Time.strptime(input, "%l:%M %p").strftime("%H:%M")
puts result
```